# Will Magento 2.0 support Twitters Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, magento, themes

Magento 2.0 does support responsive themes. They even made the standard Magento 2.0 theme responsive but I'm not sure what framework they use?

I want to start using Bootstrap but only if Magento 2.0 supports it right out of the box.

Anybody knows?

Comment: This question makes no sense. Of course you can use any frontend framework you like to build a theme for Magento. Magento itself is just a MVC application that depends on the backend logic and interaction with the front end template system for display. If you need a starting point, you may look here for example: http://magenticians.com/7-magento-bootstrap-themes

Answer (score 1):

Magento 2.0 will not ship with any specific CSS framework. It will ship with some basic CSS styling for its layout and general styling.

You are free to implement any themes for Magento in whatever framework you wish. Whether that be Bootstrap, Zurb Foundation or another.

Comment: if i create new theme extending Luma theme,How can i add Bootstrap css ?